# Exiting TBB application (task scheduler)

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, exit, tbb

I'm currently using threading building blocks to start my newest application, using the task scheduler.

If one of my tasks encounters a reason to exit the program:

1.) How can I tell all the other tasks to return?

2.) How can I verify in the main thread that all other tasks have returned, so I can safely exit the application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the question was answered already, you can use [task cancellation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506306) to stop the task from being scheduled for execution. E.g.:

```
tbb::parallel_for(0,100, [](int i){
    for(int j = 0; j < 10000000 && !task::self().is_cancelled(); j++) {
        if( must_stop )
            task::self().cancel_group_execution();
        else
            do_my_work();
    }
});
```

In the example above, the main thread will wait for all the tasks to terminate as usual since it is synchronous type of API. But if your question implies that there are asynchronously running tasks, consider using [low-level TBB scheduler API](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506304) or high-level [tbb::task_group](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506286) like:

```
tbb::task_group g;
g.run([]{ Do_my_work1(); });
g.run([]{ Do_my_work2(); });
...
g.cancel();
g.wait();
```

And finally, there is blocking termination preview feature (search for TBB_PREVIEW_WAITING_FOR_WORKERS) which would help if you need not only wait for the tasks to finish execution but also wait when TBB workers terminate.

Answer (score -1):

There are many functions [to cancel tasks](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/files/documentation/a00167.html#8bcdfdf4e6bfb76125b6de15c00b571d) and [check for cancellation](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/files/documentation/a00167.html#4db72f16210b0a991b2c134d6763a4cc). Look around...you'll find more.